# MobX: references to objects from an observable.map()

Tags: javascript, mobx

While working with observable.map() from MobX, I found that objects stored inside the map are no more linked to the original object:

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });

let user = {id: 1, name: "John"};

let myMap = observable.map();
myMap.set(user.id, user);
user.name = "Bill";
console.log(myMap.get(1).name); // John is printed, I expect Bill
```

How can I obtain the same behaviour as with plain dynamic objects? I.e. is there a method to update objects inside observable.maps from previously existing references?

```
user = {id: 1, name: "John"};
let myClassicMap = {};
myClassicMap[user.id] = user;
user.name = "Bill";
console.log(myClassicMap[1].name); // Bill is printed as expected
```

**Edit**

Using `observable.map(values, { deep: false })` I get the usual behaviour, but I don't understand if I lose something in terms of observability. In the following example the autorun isn't triggered by the change of the user.name, shouldn't it be?

```
import { observable, autorun} from 'mobx';

let myMap = observable.map({}, {deep: false});
myMap.set(user.id, user);
autorun(() => console.log(myMap));
user.name = "Bill";
```

Comment: Did you check this https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html#-observable-map-values-deep-false ?

Comment: I missed it, question updated. Now I don't understand if with a shallow map I lose something in terms of observability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because whenever you add something to a deep Array, everything you put inside also is wrapped/turned into observable:

```
let user = {id: 1, name: "John"};

let myMap = observable.map();
myMap.set(user.id, user); //here user is turned into observeable object where all curent keys are tracked
```

If you don't turn deep of: `{deep: false}` then this object wont be wrapped/turned into observerable object, thus any change you do is visible BUT these changes wont be tracked toward changes in the array itself. and thus not triggering any re-render.

Also make sure you you execute everything inside an `action()` since you enabled `configure({ enforceActions: true });`:

```
import { useStrict, configure, autorun } from 'mobx';
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';


configure({ enforceActions: true });

let user = {id: 1, name: "John"};

let myMap = observable.map();
action(() =>{
    myMap.set(user.id, user);
    user = myMap.get(1); //here we retrieved the observable object version of user.
    user.name = "Bill";
})()
console.log(myMap.get(1).name)
```